# How do I troubleshoot Composer's InvalidArgumentException with Drupal 10

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-modules

I'm a beginner who has just started a Drupal project (version 10.0.7) on a shared hosting site (Hostinger) with composer installed. When I try and install any modules through Composer I get the following error message:
*[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package drupal/pathauto. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).*

1. I've Google other people having similar problems so I've checked and the Composer JSON & LOCK files are both installed.
2. I tried changing the "minimum-stability": from "stable" to "dev"
3. I tried removing the single quotation marks around the install line e.g.'drupal/pathauto:^1.11'and trying using multiple ^^^^
4. I tried different modules but get the same result

Question: I imagine I must be missing something obvious like I'm not pointing it to the right site for downloading or there is another "stable" setting I have not adjusted. If anyone can offer suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. Posting the JSON file below.

I've tried posting the full JSON files but my post gets marked as spam.

```
"name": "drupal/legacy-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^10.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true,
            "phpstan/extension-installer": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "./"
```

Comment: You are installing drupal 10, but your repo url is:
https://packages.drupal.org/8  (for drupal 8). Is that correct?

Comment: Hi MilanG, that is correct. I tried changing it to "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/10" but I got the same error message.